# How can I export a query result from MySQL to PowerPoint through my Java aplication?

Tags: java, mysql, crystal-reports, powerpoint

I have built a `GUI` in Java so that the users from my office can search through our database, and the users need to be able to print reports in `PowerPoint` slides (one slide per register of the database), is there  a good library I can use to make the slides with my java resultset `SQL` rows? Crystal Reports doesn't seem to support `PowerPoint`.

Comment: please share your efforts

Comment: do you mean the code of my program?

Comment: yes, we can assist you if you are stuck some where

Comment: i don't have anything in my code to export my results yet so i don't think putting my code works because i haven't started the exporting results part.  I could put it if you want but it wouldn't be much helps and it's almost 500 lines.  It works fine but i need to know what library/program is available so i can export my SQL rows. Originally i was going to do this little project in php and i know there's a library called PHPPowerpoint that does this in php, but i don't know what can i use in java for this task

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have a look at

[Generate PowerPoint 2007/2010 file using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2152702/generate-powerpoint-2007-2010-file-using-java)

here they have focused on docx4j and http://poi.apache.org/slideshow/index.html which have jar to support your development, but it has support for office 2007, please update your jar version incase you are using some other office version.